# Computation of a 2D Fourier transform

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Is there an easy to compute the Fourier transform of $\frac{1}{1+x_1^2+x_2^2}$ in two variables ? And more generally, the Fourier transform of $\frac{1}{1+x_1^2+...+x_N^2}$, where $N$ denotes the dimension ?

Answer (score 0):

These functions are [radial functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_function) so their Fourier transforms are too. You might
consider the [Hankel transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hankel_transform) an easy way to compute them.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> With $\ds{\vec{k} \equiv k_{x}\,\hat{x} + k_{y}\,\hat{y}}$
>   ( where $\ds{k_{x}, k_{y} \in \mathbb{R}}$ ) and $\ds{\phi\ \equiv\ \angle\pars{\vec{k},\vec{r}}}$:

\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\left.\iint_{\mathbb{R}^{\large 2}}{\expo{\ic\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r}} \over 1 + r^{2}}\,\dd^{2}\vec{r}
\,\right\vert_{\ \vec{k}\ \not=\ \vec{0}}} = 
\int_{0}^{\infty}{r \over 1 + r^{2}}
\int_{0}^{2\pi}{\exp\pars{\ic kr\cos\pars{\phi}}}
\,\dd\phi\,\dd r
\label{1}\tag{1}
\end{align}
However,
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{2\pi}{\exp\pars{\ic kr\cos\pars{\phi}}}\,\dd\phi & =
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}{\exp\pars{-\ic kr\cos\pars{\phi}}}\,\dd\phi
\\[5mm] & =
2\int_{0}^{\pi}{\cos\pars{kr\cos\pars{\phi}}}\,\dd\phi =
\bbx{2\pi\,\mrm{J}_{0}\pars{kr}}\label{2}\tag{2}  
\end{align}

> where
>   [$\ds{\mrm{J}_{0}}$ is a Bessel Function of the First Kind](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_360.htm). The above link already reported the integration \eqref{2}.

\eqref{1} and \eqref{2} lead to
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\left.\iint_{\mathbb{R}^{\large 2}}{\expo{\ic\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r}} \over 1 + r^{2}}\,\dd^{2}\vec{r}
\,\right\vert_{\ \vec{k}\ \not=\ \vec{0}}} =
2\pi\int_{0}^{\infty}{\mrm{J}_{0}\pars{kr} \over 1 + r^{2}}
\,r\,\dd r = \bbx{\large 2\pi\,\mrm{K}_{0}\pars{k}}
\end{align}

> $\ds{\mrm{K}_{0}}$ is a *Modified Bessel Function*. The last integration is reported in
>   [this link](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.22.E46).